# What does topologically conjugate mean?

Tags: sequences-and-series

What does it mean graphically for two dynamical maps $f: X \to X$ and $g: Y \to Y$ where $X,Y \subset \mathbb{R}$ to be topologically conjugate? I read that it means that the maps have the "same dynamic behavior", but I didn't know what they meant by that. Is it related to an isomorphism in group theory? For example, if $f^n$ can get arbitrarily close to $0$ for the initial value $x_0$, does that mean $g^n$ also can get arbitrarily close to $0$ for the initial value $x_0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f: X \to X$ and $g: Y \to Y$ are topologically conjugate iff there is a homeomorphism $\varphi$ of $X$ onto $Y$ that conjugates them, i.e. such that $\varphi \circ f \circ \varphi^{-1} = g$.  You can think of $\varphi$ as a "change of variables" which makes the two maps equivalent.  The change of variables transfers a statement about the iterations of $f$ starting at $x$ 
to a statement about the iterations of $g$ starting at $\varphi(x)$.

"$f^n$ gets arbitrarily close to $0$ for the initial value $x_0$" means $f^{n_j}(x_0) \to 0$ for some subsequence $n_j$.  Since $f^{n_j} = \varphi^{-1} \circ g^{n_j} \circ \varphi$, what that says is
$\varphi^{-1} (g^{n_j} (\varphi(x_0))) \to 0$, which is equivalent to 
$g^{n_j}(\varphi(x_0)) \to \varphi(0)$, i.e. $g^n$ gets arbitrarily close to $\varphi(0)$ for the initial value $\varphi(x_0)$.

Comment: Good explanation!